# How can I count with two criteria in google spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, countif

I am quite confused on how this function...
I am trying to count date and activity but inorder to count activity, it should be not blank and it follows the corresponding date. How can I code it? Tried countifs but I can't make it work.
Thanks in advance

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XfAp1RKp55jDRj7jSTIPGQSvy1GHH8KE-VR-vJmCF3w/edit?usp=drivesdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your formula should be:

```
=COUNTIFS(A$2:A, D2, B$2:B, "<>")
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you, it's much simpler than I expected.